# I am stuck on this proof (linear algebra) prove that $Dim (nullST) \leq slantdim(nullS)+dim(nullT)$

Tags: linear-algebra

suppose U and V are finite dimensional vector spaces and $S \in L(V,W)$ and $T \in L(U,V)$ prove that  $ Dim (nullST) \leqslant dim(nullS)+dim(nullT)$

I have been stuck on proofing this for a while, I understand why it is true but can't seem to find a way to prove it.

My thought proces: $null(ST)$ = All the vectors of $U$ that get mapped to the $null(S)$, the $NullT$ is a subspace of the $NullST$, Don't know for sure but I think there doens't exist a linear map between $Null(ST)$ and the $Null(S)$ that makes the $dim(Null(S))$ higher then the $dim(Null(ST))$ Tell me if im somewhere wrong tips and well explained solutions are welcome

Comment: You may want to look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1741928/prove-that-dimnullspacest-dimnullspacet-dimranget-∩-nullspa?rq=1

Comment: @ Anurang A Good catch I will have a look and see what is usefull

Comment: This follows at once from the rank-nullity theorem. By apply the theorem to $T$ on $U$, $S$ on $V$, and $S$ on $T(U)$.